# Using DomDocument to Replace an <a> tag with Text

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

I'm looking to replace `<a>` tag in string with some text. My code is as follows

```
$string = 'This link <a href="somedomain.com">Some Domain</a> needs to be removed';

        $domdocument = new \DOMDocument();
        $domdocument->loadHTML($string, LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD | LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);
        $link = $domdocument->getElementsByTagName('a')[0];

        $replacement_link = $domdocument->createTextNode("HELLO WORLD");
        $domdocument->appendChild($replacement_link);
        $domdocument->replaceChild($link, $replacement_link);
        $output = $domdocument->saveHTML();
        dd($output);

// Expected output: 'This link HELLO WORLD needs to be removed'
```

However, I get the `$string` back as output, without any replacement. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There may be other ways to do it, but try the following:

Assuming that your string is embedded in a tag like:

```
$string = '<p>This link <a href="somedomain.com">Some Domain</a> needs to be removed</p>';
```

Change your code to:

```
$domdocument = new \DOMDocument();
$domdocument->loadHTML($string, LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD | LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);
$link = $domdocument->getElementsByTagName('a')[0];

#new part:
$linkParent = $domdocument->getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
$link->textContent = "HELLO WORLD";
$linkParent->textContent = $linkParent->nodeValue;
$output = $domdocument->saveHTML();
echo($output);
```

Output should be:

```
<p>This link HELLO WORLD needs to be removed</p>
```

Comment: This works as expected. But can't figure out why do we need `$linkParent`? Also, could you point out why my code doesn't work? Trying to get my brain around the logical flow of how domDocument works.

Comment: @TheBigK You have two problems w/ your code - first, `$domdocument->appendChild($replacement_link);` appends a child to the document root element, not the element in which the `<a>` node is (which in my answer is `<p>`). After appending, `$replacement_link` becomes a sibling, not a child, of `<a>`'s parent, so your subsequent `replaceChild()` doesn't work. Also, the syntax for `replaceChild()` is `replaceChild(new, old)`; your `replaceChild($link, $replacement_link)` is in reverse. If you fix both issues, it should work, or you can use the shortcut in my answer...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that replacement node should not be **appended** to document before replacing. According to docs: **This function replaces the child child with the passed new node. If the node is already a child it will not be added a second time. If the replacement succeeds the old node is returned.**

Instead, it should be **imported** into the document. Try to replace this line

```
$domdocument->appendChild($replacement_link);
```

with this

```
$domdocument->importNode($replacement_link, true);
```

(according to this example https://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.replacechild.php#48485)

Comment: Just replacing that line throws ` DOMException Not Found Error`. Reading through the link you've shared.